# How to show the ticks on y-axis as 10-based?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot. I want it shows y-axis as the second posted image

[image] -

[image] - the annotations of which I want

Comment: Have you try `scale_y_log10` function ? If it is not what you are looking for, can you provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I used the code as follows. But whatever I change the minor part, I can't get what I expected.
p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = date, y = total_cases, color = location)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "1 month",
    labels = date_format("%b %d")
    ) +
  scale_y_log10(
    breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))
    ) +
  xlab(label = "Date (Y2020)") +
  ylab(label = "Total cases")
ggplotly()

Comment: Hi Peter. The issue is probably not related to `ggplot2`. Checked on some example data. And to me everything looks fine. However, when converting to plotly via ´ggplotly` the labels break.

Comment: @stefan, thank you for the idea. Do you know a fix?

Comment: Hi Peter. Unfortunately no. Using math format or greek letters, super- and subscripts in ggplot2 for axis and tick labels requires an object of type `expression()`. However at least with `ggplotly` this seems not possible (at the moment). Either I get the warning `In is.na(ticktext) :is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'` or the error `Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors`. I would suggest to check the documentation of plotly and/or edit your question to focus on this issue.

Comment: Thanks to Stefan. Your reply solved my confusion.